# "Time travel" difference in double slit experiment

Tags: optics, waves, interference, double-slit-experiment

In double slit experiment, as in following [figure](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/slits.html)
[image]

We calculate the relative phase via $$\Delta \phi_0 = \frac{2\pi \delta}{\lambda} $$ where $\delta$ denote the two path distance difference in figure, $\lambda$ is the wave length.

Why don't we consider the time traveling difference? The upper path may arrive first, so naively thinking we should consider $$\Delta \phi^{\prime} = \omega \Delta t $$ contribution. where $$\Delta t = \frac{\delta}{c} $$ so $$\Delta \phi^{\prime}=2\pi f \frac{\delta}{c}=2\pi \frac{\delta}{\lambda}$$

The total phase difference
$$\Delta \phi = \Delta \phi_0 + \Delta \phi^{\prime}= \frac{4\pi \delta}{\lambda}$$

Comment: A stupid question that I proposed! If we think this process carefully, imagine how two waves arrive the screen, we shouldn't consider time effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we look at the screen at a time $t$, we look at the interference of all the waves that reach the screen at that time $t$. They have all the same time phase and the time traveling difference is zero.